# windows media buttons on Remote Control dont work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-media-player

I have a remote control pointing at the PC / TV

CTRL + P on the keyboard works and Plays / Pauses within the application.

The remote control can Play / Pause in Media Player but it doesnt work in a WPF app.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModifierKeys mk = ((ModifierKeys)(ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift));
        MyPlayPause.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Control));
        MyStop.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control));
        MyRewind.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.B,mk));
        MyFastForward.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F,mk));
    }
```

My XAML is

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static  RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyPlayPause}" Executed="MyPlayPauseEvent"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyStop}" Executed="MyStopEvent"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyFastForward}" Executed="MyFastForwardEvent" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyRewind}" Executed="MyRewindEvent" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The events work for rewind and fast forward, but not for Play/Pause and Stop.

I tried downloading Media Glass http://mediaglass.codeplex.com/ and this has the same issue on the remote when pressing CTRL + P

I have found out that by applying the following

```
 System.Windows.Input.Key wpfLeftKey = Key.LeftCtrl;
 var formsKey = (Forms.Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfLeftKey);
```

I get different results from my output

```
 Windows 32 = LControlKey 
 WPF = LeftControl
```

My thinking is that the remote control is programmed to send out LControlKey

Therefore what I need to do is raise an event when the Win32 app records LControlKey and force the event to fire. Any suggestions. (After InitiliseComponent()?

I could be completey of the beaten track here, or could be right. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Key Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx)

Comment: Ive added <Window.InputBindings> <InputBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyPlayPause}" Gesture="P"></InputBinding> <InputBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyStop}" Gesture="LControlKey+S"/> </Window.InputBindings>, i get the error 'No matching constructor found on type 'System.Windows.Input.InputBinding'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.' Line number '14' and line position '10'.

Comment: Ive added <Window.InputBindings> <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyPlayPause}" CommandParameter="P" Gesture="CTRL+P" /> <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static RemoteControlTest:MainWindow.MyStop}" CommandParameter="S" Gesture="CTRL+S" /> </Window.InputBindings> It does the same thing :(

Comment: it worked when I added the media key binding   MyPlayPause.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.MediaPlayPause)); as the remote control was sending a different command through